# Problem with MSVC includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm working on making a library. Eventually I will use CMake but right now I'm just using MSVC.

First my directory structure (as an example) will be as follows:

```
LibRoot
 blah.h
   SubRoot
     bloop.h
```

The way I used to include blah in bloop was by doing:

```
#include "../blah.h"
```

I looked at many other libraries and they did not do this, they instead did:

```
#include "LibRoot/blah.h"
```

So I did this and now MSVC cannot find this include file. How come it works on another MSVC based lib, but mine does not? Is there a certain flag that I must set or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add whatever directory **LibRoot** is in to the **Additional Include Directories** of the project's properties (on the **C/C++ - General** page).

Comment: Alright thanks! So is this proper practice for making a X platform library?